# Is there a way to plot a KDE curve where the bandwidth is determined by asymmetric confidence intervals?

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a dataset containing central values and their associated confidence intervals which are asymmetric (e.g. a central value of 50m, 95% lower bound of 10m and 95% upper bound of 60m, as opposed to symmetrical intervals such as 95% lower bound of 40m, central value of 50m and 95% upper interval of 60m). I wish to plot a KDE curve of all my central values (so the summed probability) using the confidence intervals as the bandwidth. This involves summing asymmetric confidence intervals. Has anybody had any experience with this using either seaborn or sci-kit for example?

```
# Extract central values, lower bounds, and upper bounds
central_values = df['central value'].values
lower_bounds = df['95% lower bound'].values
upper_bounds = df['95% upper bound'].values

# Create a figure and a single set of axes for the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))

# Initialize an array to store the histogram data
hist_data = []

# Initialize an array to store the combined KDE estimate
combined_density = np.zeros(1000)

# Loop through the data points and calculate the KDE estimate for each
for i in range(len(central_values)):
    if lower_bounds[i] == upper_bounds[i]:
        continue  # Skip data points with zero uncertainty

    data_point = np.random.uniform(lower_bounds[i], upper_bounds[i], size=1000)  
    # Calculate a bandwidth for this data point based on its confidence interval
    bandwidth = max((upper_bounds[i] - lower_bounds[i]) * 0.1, 1e-3)  

    # Create a KDE model for this data point with the calculated bandwidth
    kde = KernelDensity(bandwidth=bandwidth)
    kde.fit(data_point.reshape(-1, 1))

    # Define x values for the KDE plot
    x_values = np.linspace(data_point.min() - 50, data_point.max() + 50, 1000)

    # Calculate the log density and transform to probability density
    log_density = kde.score_samples(x_values.reshape(-1, 1))
    density = np.exp(log_density)

    # Sum the KDE estimate for this data point to the combined KDE
    combined_density += density

    # Store data for histogram
    hist_data.extend(data_point)

# Plot the combined KDE estimate for the entire dataset
plt.plot(x_values, combined_density, linewidth=2, label='Stacked Custom Bandwidth KDE')

# Create a histogram
plt.hist(hist_data, bins=20, color='lightgray', edgecolor='black', alpha=0.7,    label='Histogram')
```